# Prometheus Probe CRD doesn't probe targets

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I am using Prometheus Probe CRD and Blackbox exporter to scrape static targets. But, when I checked in Blackbox exporter, I don't see specified targets being probed at all.

I was able to probe targets using Blackbox exporter and additionalScrapeConfigs in values file of Prometheus exporter but it doesn't work with Probe CRD.

Here is my Probe custom object config,

```
kind: Probe
metadata:
  name: probe-crd
  namespace: prometheus
spec:
  jobName: probe-crd
  prober:
    url: prometheus-blackbox-exporter:9115
  targets:
    staticConfig:
      static:
      - https://www.google.com
```

Blackbox exporter service is running on port 9115. Can someone please let me know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you have the appropriate matching configured in your `kind: Prometheus` definition(s):

```
probeNamespaceSelector: {}
probeSelector: {}
```

More details on configuring those is in https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/api.md

Comment: I have tried setting `prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    probeNamespaceSelector: {}
    probeSelector: {}` in my prometheus values chart file, is that how it is suppost to be because it is still not working for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `release: name_of_your_promy_helm_release` label

Answer (score 0):

Just checked my working config here and I have no protocol schema on the target url:

```
targets:
  staticConfig:
    static:
    - www.google.com
```

But I just added one with https:// in front. It still got picked up, but returned http status 0 all the time.

So I guess, if you have your selectors correct, it is surely missing rights. Make sure you have your `ServiceAccount`, `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding` correctly setup.